# SharePoint 2010 service pack 2 and FAST Search

Tags: enterprise-search, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint, service-pack, service-pack-2

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm that is currently on Feb 2013 CU.  I plan to upgrade this to service pack 2.  However, there is a separate FAST search server being used that I noticed is at the RTM version (14.0.4763.1000).  I found the FAST version by going to C:\FASTSearch\installer\files on the server.  There doesn't seem to be another way to see the version.

Will upgrading to SharePoint service pack 2 on the farm servers impact the FAST search version at all?  I noticed there is a separate service pack 2 just for FAST search. Is that necessary?

Would I install the FAST service pack the same way I would the regular service pack?  Install bits, run config wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Fast Search Server Version by  In Control Panel, under Programs and Features, click "Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint" and you will see the version number here as well.Also click on View installed updates to see all installed updates.

Fast search server is seprate product then the Sharepoint, So SharePoint patches/Hotfix doesnot have dependencies on it.

But it is really good to keep the product upto date with latest CU/SP. As you are already applying the update to sharepoint farm, i would also Apply the Fast Service Pack to the search farm.

Comment: What about the installation method?  Same as SharePoint SP 2?

Comment: Little different at psconfig level...check thishttps://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285624(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: If I install SharePoint 2010 SERVER service pack 2, do I also need to install Foundation service pack 2, or is it included?

Comment: Service Pack 2 for server include the Foundation in it